# Closing or Removing a Trello Board When You are Not the Administrator

Tags: trello

I am the top-level organization owner. An employee who was the administrator of a Trello board left recently and I am unable to rename or delete the board. I have already removed his account from the organization.

Is there a way to rename and/or preferably delete the board?